# Barra de notificaciones Android

Tags: flutter, interfaz-gráfica, dart

[image: Reproductor]

Buenas noches estoy haciendo una APP de Radio con Flutter y Dart quiero implementar lo de la imagen que al salir de la app (NO cerrar) se quede en reproducción. Alguien sabe como se le llama a ese tipo de efecto o que es.

Answer (score -1):

[image: APP RADIO]

Igual si alguien sabe como hacer que se vea la lista de reproducción de fondo y abajo el estado de la radio que sigue sonando como la siguiente imagen